# Error in using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my main activity code

```
  import android.app.Fragment;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout, container,false);
}
```

}

Below is the code for my activity_main.xml file containning two fragments

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.softmya.fragments.FirstFragment"
    android:id="@+id/firstFragment1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:name="com.softmya.fragments.SecondFragment"
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment2"
    android:layout_weight="1"  
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code for my Fragments 
FirstFragment.java

```
     package com.softmya.fragments;

     import android.app.Fragment;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;

     public class FirstFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout, container,false);
}
```

}

FirstFragment Layout

```
 <LinearLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/lblFragment1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="This is fragment #1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Second Fragment Code is also exactly similar to the the FirstFragment.java code Except for the For the class name and the layout being inflated

Error Log

```
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.softmya.fragments/com.softmya.fragments.MainActivity}:       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at com.softmya.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     ... 11 more
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:        com.softmya.fragments.FirstFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:577)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
   08-07 23:34:01.507: E/AndroidRuntime(23268):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: the first class posted is a activity class?

Comment: the error is not in any code you provided here, somewhere you are trying to cast `FirstFragment` to a `Fragment`

Comment: Sorry by mistake added. The wrong code dont know what was the error earlier but now my code is running dont have any idea how!!!!!!!! Now I will try to bring the error back to know what happened :P

Answer (score 0):

Try changing activity_main.xml to look like the following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!--fragment-->
<com.softmya.fragments.FirstFragment
    android:id="@+id/firstFragment1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--fragment-->
<com.softmya.fragments.SecondFragment    
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment2"
    android:layout_weight="1"  
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: To achieve what you originally were after, I think you replace "fragment" with "view" or "View".

Comment: Means? Didn't get you?